# How common are self-funded PhDs in the STEM fields in U.S. universities?

Tags: phd, funding, united-states, stem

I met a PhD student that is completely self-funded at our engineering college .  Our university is notorious for being one of the most expensive schools to attend; I can't imagine someone funding his own graduate studies for five/six years, right after paying for an undergrad education.

He did land an important internship at a large hedge fund, though, so I'm guessing in the long run, if he lands in finance, it could be all worth it.

My question is: are self-funded PhDs in the STEM fields at U.S. universities pretty common?

Comment: There's a strong norm against it; "you should not be paying for your own PhD tuition, you should be earning a stipend" is stock advice for undergraduates in the USA contemplating graduate school.  The situation might be different for people returning to academia after some time in industry, though.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [Survey of Earned Doctorates](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/srvydoctorates/), a large-scale survey of students who earn doctoral degrees from U.S. institutions,

- In the life sciences, 9% report "own resources" as primary source of support.
- In the physical sciences, 3.8% report "own resources" as primary source of support.
- In the social sciences, 25.3% report "own resources" as primary source of support.
- In engineering, 3.8% report "own resources" as primary source of support.

See [TABLE 35. Doctorate recipients' primary source of financial support, by broad field of study, sex, citizenship status, ethnicity, and race: 2014](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/2016/nsf16300/data/tab35.pdf).

Comment: There may be some bias because self-funded students are unusual. For several years, I was both self-funded and the only over-50 female computer science graduate student on a campus. I did not complete surveys that asked for any confidential information unless they indicated a minimum group size for statistics.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan In the SED, data is not disclosed for subgroups of small size. These are listed as "D = suppressed to avoid disclosure of confidential information" in the table. A discussion of the specific data suppression policy is available in [Protecting and Accessing Data from the Survey of Earned Doctorates](http://www.nap.edu/catalog/12797/protecting-and-accessing-data-from-the-survey-of-earned-doctorates) (free to read online with no login required)

Comment: That is what I like to see in a survey, so I would have answered that one.